# pandas.read_gbq() "invalid credential" error

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to fetch my bigquery table using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
query = "SELECT * FROM my_data.2019 LIMIT 10"
project_id = "my-project"
table = pd.read_gbq(query=query, project_id=project_id, reauth=False)
table.head()
```

After executing the code I get the following error:

> GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/jobs:
>   Invalid credential

I run this code from a jupyter notebook server spawned by a jupyterhub that I created. It worked before! When I run it on jupyter's public notebook server for example, it works well.

Comment: do you have a valid `secrets.key` file set in your `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']`?

Comment: @WillianFuks thanks for your reply! I didn't have this variable..added it now and it's working!..I wonder though, how does the code run when I just open a public notebook without setting the environment variable...

Comment: where is this public notebook hosted?

Comment: it's hosted on mybinder.org

Comment: hmm not sure why it works then. Maybe you can try printing what's in the `os.environ` and see if there's already a pre-setup made for you.